# Trying to set dynamically added html table data to local storage and to retrieve it when refreshing or reloading the app

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with dynamically added data> Im trying to save that data in local storage and then also have the data still in the table when the table is refreshed or the app is re-opened.

```
    <div id="title">
        <h1>JobPad</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table id='table' border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th id='number'>RO/Tag Number</th>
                    <th id='job'>Description</th>
                    <th id='spiff'>Spiff</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input id="input" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <table id="total-hrs">
            <th class="hrs">Total Spiff</th>
            <td><input id="total"></td>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button id="btn-calc" type="button" id="btn-calc" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-light" onclick='calculate()'>Calculate</button>
        <button id="btn-save" type="button" id="btn-save" value="Save" class="btn btn-light" onclick='storeInfo()'>Save</button>
        <button id="btn-save" type="button" id="btn-save" value="Save" class="btn btn-light" onclick='removeInfo()'>Delete</button>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>


    function storeInfo() {

    const appData = document.getElementById('input').value

    let data;

    if (localStorage.getItem('data') === null) {
        data = [];
    } else {
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    }
    data.push(appData)
        // console.log(appData)
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

So far I am able to save only the data from first cell of the table. Also it does not reload with the app when refreshed or re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

You're only saving from one input because every input has the same `id` attribute.

> The `id` attribute defines an identifier which must be unique in the whole document. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

You could put your table headings in `<thead>` and table rows in `<tbody>` to make indexing your rows a little easier (for reference sake).

Finally, your inputs could do with a little more semantic meaning. Drop the `id` and provide a meaningful `name` attribute like `name="spiff"`, etc. This will give you much more control over how you structure your data and when it comes to storing/restoring from localStorage.

My suggestion would be to add names to your inputs, similar to your table heading ID's (number, job, spiff).

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="number" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="job" type="text"></td>
    <td><input name="spiff" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Create two functions, one that stores data and another that restores. Both will behave in somewhat the opposite fashion to each other but rely heavily on the available rows.

```
const store = () => {
  // 1. iterate table rows
  // 2. iterate inputs within these rows
  // 3. create plain object where key = input.name, value = input.value
  // 4. push object to collection array
  // 5. stringify and store array in localStorage
}

const restore = () => {
  // 1. gather data from localStorage, if any
  // 2. iterate table rows, referenced by index
  // 3. find inputs by stored data keys and populate value
  //    data keys and table row indexes work hand-in-hand here
}
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuebizzle/0437w1e6/) that demonstrates exactly this. Populate the table and click **Save**, then click **Reset** to clear the table values, followed by **Restore** which restores data from localStorage. **Refresh** the page to verify.

> Code Snippet on stackoverflow doesn't work well with localStorage, at least from my experience, due to security concerns.

Good luck.

Comment: Oh wow I see what you did. That's what I was going for. I like the buttons you added. Thank you so much for your help. I made all the id's inputs thinking it would get all of them together. Still learning...